# Should "Which original retrocomputer OS's are still maintained and updated today, for original hardware?" be a community wiki Q&A pair?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, community-wiki

[Which original retrocomputer OS's are still maintained and updated today, for original hardware?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2379/621)

This question is based on my upvoted comment [here](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2379/which-original-retrocomputer-oss-are-still-maintained-and-updated-today-for-or#comment4804_2379).

To me, this is a list question.  Answers would include the name of the OS, the date last updated, and a link to the build (which is [already happening](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2380/621)).

Should we try the Community Wiki Q&A model discussed [here](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/381/621) for this question?

Related here on meta: [Do we want list questions?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/380/621)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I believe this question is a good candidate for a Community Wiki model and possibly a moderator Wiki Lock.  There would be a single answer which any user could edit to add additional information, instead of several incomplete answers.

Comment: There's a type of lock specifically for this purpose that would not prevent editing the question.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Ah yes, I believe the technical term is a "Wiki Lock" as seen with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2415822) book list.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: In the mod tools it says "Wiki Answer", but that doesn't sound like a lock outside the context of the lock menu.

Comment: My primary desire would be that the Q&A be readily discoverable by as many means as possible - Google search, StackExchange search, "Related Posts", etc. If locking to a Wiki limits discoverability of useful content, then it undermines the broader purpose of the site as a knowledge base.

Comment: @BrianH I don't see how locking the post would impact any of those things.

Comment: @BrianH Locking a post only affects how it can be edited and _nothing_ else. This sort of lock would mean that no new answers could be posted, by everything could still be edited, and that would mean that information would all be organised in one answer.